# Callback после закрытия окна при аутентификации с помощью Google+("Sign In with Google")?

Tags: javascript, google-plus

Добрый день! В функцию передается объект со свойством callback, которое вызывается после успешной аутентификации:

```
gapi.auth.signIn({callback: 'someFunction'});
```

Есть ли возможность вызвать такой же callback, только после закрытия "Окна аутентификации Google"? (Например, пользователь передумал логиниться и закрыл окно):

```
gapi.auth.signIn({callbackAfterCloseWindow: 'someFunctionAfterClose'});
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Коллбэк закрытия можно слушать только у окна браузера.

```
$(window).bind("beforeunload", function() { 
    return inFormOrLink || confirm("Do you really want to close?"); 
})
```

Comment: Спасибо, но как в таком случае в google+ javascript api получить ссылку на открытое окно? Т.е. как обратиться к "Окну аутентификации Google", чтобы установить данное событие?

Comment: Ответ подразумевал, что никак. Окно создается подгружаемым скриптом гугл апи. Снаружи туда доступа нет.

Comment: Жаль, конечно, в facebook с этим делом как-то более лучше все обстоит, я имею ввиду возвращается статус. Спасибо!